# How does Cellminer's "Cross-correlations of transcripts, drugs, and microRNAs" work

Tags: statistics, gene

I have seen one of [Cellminer tools](https://discover.nci.nih.gov/cellminer/). I am not sure how do they calculate the cross correlation of the genes, what does it actually mean? Based on what databases?

For example if I take their example input ([HUGO](http://www.genenames.org/) format):

```
abcb1
BRCA2
CNBP
```

I get the following cross correlation matrix (based on what signals).

```
Identifier      abcb1   BRCA2   CNBP
abcb1           1      -0.142   0.069
BRCA2          -0.142   1       0.176
CNBP           0.069    0.176   1
```

Comment: You're probably best asking the authors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [article](http://cancerres.aacrjournals.org/content/72/14/3499.full) describing Cellminer says about the cross-correlations:

> ... a cross-correlation table of the resultant z-scores can be
>   generated ...

On page 3503

And the z-scores are defined previously as:

> The tool output includes relative transcript intensity presented
>   as z-scores...